# html response data id not able to be used as string in facebook API call

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, object, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the facebook API to get photos of users. First I do this, to get an array of photo id's from facebook:

```
function getPhotos() {
    FB.api(
      "/me/photos?type=tagged",
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log(response.data[0].id);
          displayPhotos(response.data[0].id);
        }
        else {
          console.log(response.error);
        }
      }
   );
}
```

The above step works fine, and I get back an array of image ids in the `response.data` object. Then I want to take just the first image and send it to another function here, so that I can get and display the first picture.

```
function displayPhotos(photoId) {
    FB.api(
      "/"+photoId,
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log("display photos response" + response);
          var container = document.getElementById("photos");
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = response;
          container.appendChild(img);
        }
        else {
          console.log(response.error);
        }
      }
   );
}
```

However, when the response.data[0].id gets passed from one function to the other, it seems to go from being a string to being an object, which doesn't work for the second API call. I see in my developer console when the second function tries to make its call:

`GET http://localhost/ropes/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)`

I want where it says `[object%20Object]` to be the string id from the first `response.data[0]` object.

Comment: What does `response.data[0].id` look like in the console?

Comment: @OliverJ90 just a normal string..a number as a string...for example `659475728940`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, you helped push me in the right direction, I have since modified my code to get the `profile pictures` album and display those photos, to solve the problem I had to do a few things: 1.) add `/picture` to the end of the photo id, to get a response that had a url in it. Also, I just used the whole url starting with `http://...`:

```
  function getAlbums() {
    FB.api(
      "/me/albums",
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log(response);
          for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
            if(response.data[i].name == "Profile Pictures") {
              console.log(response.data[i].name);
              var myId = '/'+response.data[i].id;
              getPhotos(myId);
            }
            else {
              //
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          console.log(response.error);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  function getPhotos(albumId) {
    //alert(typeof photoId);
    FB.api(
      'http://graph.facebook.com'+albumId+'/photos',
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log(response);
          for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
              var myId = '/'+response.data[i].id;
              displayPhotos(myId);
          }
        }
        else {
          console.log("This error?");
          console.log(response.error);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  function displayPhotos(photoId) {
    //alert(typeof photoId);
    FB.api(
      'http://graph.facebook.com'+photoId+'/picture?type=thumbnail',
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log(response);
          var container = document.getElementById("photos");
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = response.data.url;
          container.appendChild(img);
        }
        else {
          console.log("This error?");
          console.log(response.error);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it explicitly:

```
var myId = response.data[0].id;
displayPhotos(myId);
```

Comment: it looks like json.stringify makes the string (number) look like this `"\ 659475728940"`...it added some backslashes and quotes

Comment: `var myId = response.data[0].id;
displayPhotos(myId);` doesnt work either - same problem of [object Object]

Comment: Very confusing, have you tried seeing exactly what `photoId` is when it gets appended to "/" in the second function? Try `alert(typeof photoId)` and see what it says, should say string or number. If that is the case, try creating the string before you pass it into the `FB.api(...` i.e: `var myStr = "/"+photoId` then pass myStr in place of `"/"+photoId`

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the error message resp. Its cause here – it does not result from accessing `response.data[0].id`, that value is fine.

It comes from the point where you try to use the response of your *second* API call to generate and request an image,

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = response;
```

`response` is an object here, and therefore when you assign it to the `src` property of the `img` object, it needs to get converted to a string value. *That* results in `[Object object]`, and therefore your browser now makes a request for `http://localhost/ropes/[object%20Object]`, because that is what you assigned as the image source.

Go log the `response` object to console before those lines – inspect it, to see what properties it contains, and then assign the value of the appropriate property to the img `src`.

Comment: I inspected the response using `JSON.stringify` and there is only an `id` field...and a `created_at` field with a timestamp...it doesn't seem to be sending me back an image at all...its sending me the same data that i got in the first step of getting an array of all the tagged photos.

Comment: Just do a simple `console.log(response)` – no stringify, no concatenation with any other strings – and inspect the object in console.

Comment: same thing basically...it outputs `Object { created_time: "2012-06-25T01:53:49+0000", id: "659475728940" }` nothing that it looks like i would use as `src` for image data. actually with the object it looks like there is a field `_proto_` with an `Object` for its data...could that be the picture data?